# How to let git check for updates on the master server?

Tags: linux, git

I have very poor knowledge about git and would like to ask for help.

I have a linux(-only) application which shall only be "downloaded" (i.e. cloned) with git. On startup, the app shall ask the git "master server" (github) for whether there are updates.

Does git offer a command to check for whether there is an update (without really updating - only checking)? Furthermore, can my app read the return value of that command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to merge, you can just `git fetch yourremote/yourbranch`, the remote/branch specification usually being `origin/master`. You could then parse the output of the command to see if new commits are actually present. You can refer to the latest fetched commit as either `yourremote/yourbranch` or possibly by the symref `FETCH_HEAD`.

**Note:** I was reminded that `FETCH_HEAD` refers to the last branch that was fetched. Hence in general you cannot rely on `git fetch yourremote` with `FETCH_HEAD` since the former fetches all tracked branches, thus the latter may not refer to `yourbranch`. Additionally,

- you end up fetching more than strictly necessary.
- also refer to [Jefromi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7697730/915044) to view but not actually downloaded changes
- the following are not necessarily the most compact formats, just readable examples.

That being said, here are some options for checking for updates of a remote branch, which we will denote with `yourremote/yourbranch`:

**0.** Handling errors in the following operations:

**0.1** If you attempt to `git fetch yourremote`, and `git` gives you an error like

```
conq: repository does not exist.
```

that probably means you don't have that remote-string defined. Check your defined remote-strings with `git remote --verbose`, then `git remote add yourremote yourremoteURI` as needed.

**0.2** If `git` gives you an error like

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'yourremote/yourbranch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

that probably means you don't have `yourremote/yourbranch` locally. I'll leave it to someone more knowledgeable to explain what it means to have something remote locally :-) but will say here only that you should be able to fix that error with

```
git fetch yourremote
```

after which you should be able to repeat your desired command successfully. (Provided you have defined `git remote yourremote` correctly: see previous item.)

**1.** If you need detailed information, `git show yourremote/yourbranch` and compare it to the current `git show yourbranch`

**2.** If you only want to see the differences, `git diff yourbranch yourremote/yourbranch`

**3.** If you prefer to make comparisons on the hash only, compare `git rev-parse yourremote/yourbranch` to `git rev-parse yourbranch`

**4.** If you want to use the log to backtrack what happened, you can do something like `git log --pretty=oneline yourremote/yourbranch...yourbranch` (note use of **three** dots).

Comment: Cool, thanks, I just did that, and then: git diff --name-only HEAD origin/master. It shows all the changes to me.

Comment: But I have two other issues: (1) Can I also show the commit messages instead? (2) git diff offers me a text editor for the differences. I need something that I can parse with my app.

Comment: Also or in place of? As added above, `git show` gives you more or less anything you want. You can still use `--pretty=YOURFORMATHERE` to format the message. `git diff HEAD FETCH_HEAD` does not prompt you for editing.

Comment: Great! (2) can be solved by the --no-pager option. So all I do now is: `git fetch origin && git --no-pager log --pretty=oneline FETCH_HEAD...HEAD`

Comment: Good advice about various command, but huge problem with the arguments: `git fetch origin` updates *all* remote branches for origin, and whichever one happens to be fetched last is left in `FETCH_HEAD`. Use `origin/master` or another specific remote branch.

Comment: Replace the FETCH_HEADs in the examples and you get a +1!

Comment: Is now ok in your opinion, or should I pick the specific remote branch? I feel that for a simple repo, most likely tracking master only, that notation would be overkill.

Comment: How is it overkill? It's not even much longer, and it'll always do what you want. It's just the right way to do it. Why bother with `FETCH_HEAD` unless you really need to? And remember, on SO, it's better to err on the side of generality, because someone can quite easily find this answer in two years, and be in a completely different situation from the OP.

Comment: You are right, so I generalised and kept a reminder related to the deceptive `FETCH_HEAD`.

Answer (score 3):

If you really don't want to actually use bandwidth and fetch new commits, but just check whether there is anything to fetch, you can use:

```
git fetch --dry-run [remote]
```

where `[remote]` defaults to `origin`. You'll have to parse the output, though, which looks something like this:

```
From git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git
   2e49dab..7f41b6b  master     -> origin/master
```

so it's really much easier to just fetch everything (`git fetch [remote]`), and then look at the diff/log e.g. between `master` and `[remote]/master`.

Comment: On hindsight, to be honest this should be considered the real answer to the question. I added a reference in my answer.

Comment: @I10i: I think the diff/log variety in your answer is also helpful to the OP; that's why I didn't try to replicate it here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say git fetch is a potential solution.  It only updates the index, not working code.  In cases of large commit sets, this would involve a download of compressed files/info, so it may be more than you want, but it is the most useful download you can do.